# I'm working on a leveling system bot but i want to add xp every 5 second when the user join voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

i want to add xp when the user join voice channel by interval but when they leave the channel it still givexp

my code

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID; 
  
   const interval = setInterval (() => {
     if (newUserChannel) {
const user =  Levels.fetch(newMember.id, newMember.guild.id);
console.log(`${newMember.id} server ${newMember.guild.id} level : ${user.level} xp : ${user.xp}`)


Levels.appendXp(newMember.id, newMember.guild.id, 1)



     }else {
       const channel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "848698518537633895")
       
       channel.send("left channel ").then(clearInterval(interval))
       }
   }, 5000)})
```

Answer (score 1):

`interval` is a local variable that is created each time the [`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event occurs.

Thus, when the user leaves, <del>you are essentially calling `clearInterval(undefined);`</del> you are clearing a new interval, which does nothing. The state object emitted by this event does not update by itself.

You need to instead store these intervals in an object outside of the event listener; something like this:

```js
const XPIntervals = {};

client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
  const connected = !!newState.channelID,
    userId = newState.id;

  if (connected) {
    // intervals don't exist yet
    if (typeof XPIntervals[userId] === "undefined") {
      XPIntervals[userId] = setInterval(() => {
        increaseExp();
      }, 5e3 /* 5 seconds */);
    }
  } else {
    // user left, clear the interval
    clearInterval(XPIntervals[userId]);

    // remove the interval object, so it can be created again later
    delete XPIntervals[userId];
  }
});
```